# Viginere ciphere help needed

Tags: python

I am trying to replicate the viginere cipher at home 
when this runs the outcome keyword is shifted by one less place than it should be?? any help??

while True:
    Alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'#these are the letters that can be inputted

```
def main():
    Mode = input("Press 1 for encryption or 2 for decyrption:")#this will allow the user to select whether to encode or decode


    if Mode == '1':#this will allow user to encrypt when 1 is pressed
        myMessage = input ("Enter a message to encrypt:")#this allows the user to enter the message they would like to be encrypted
        myKey = input("Enter a keyword to use:")#this allows the user to enter what keyword they would like to encypt by
        x = encryptM(myKey, myMessage)
    elif Mode == '2':#this will allow user to decrypt when 2 is pressed
        myMessage = input ("Enter a message to decrypt:")#this allows the user to enter the message they would like to be encrypted
        myKey = input("Enter a keyword to use:")#this allows the user to enter what keyword they would like to encypt by
        x = decryptM(myKey, myMessage)



    print("Your encrypted message is: " +x ) #this will print the encrypted or decrypted message to the user 

def encryptM(key, message):
    return translateM(key, message, 'encrypt')

def decryptM(key, message):
    return translateM(key, message, 'decrypt')

def translateM(key, message, mode):
    x = []

    keyIndex = 0
    key = key.upper()

    for symbol in message:
        num = Alphabet.find(symbol.upper())
        if num != -1:
            if mode == 'encrypt':
                num += Alphabet.find(key[keyIndex])#this will add the number from the keyword with the encryption number
            elif mode == 'decrypt':
                num -= Alphabet.find(key[keyIndex])#this will take away the number from the keyword from the decryption number

            num %= len(Alphabet)#this converts the alphabet string into numbers
            #this function will add the alphabet string to the end of the key so they can be added
            if symbol.isupper():
                x.append(Alphabet[num])
            elif symbol.islower():
                x.append(Alphabet[num].lower())

            keyIndex += 1
            if keyIndex == len(key):
                keyIndex = 0
    return "".join(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main( )

print (' ')#this adds a line between the loops
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `Alphabet.find` returns index in the array (i.e. your `Alphabet` string) and indices of the characters are *zero-based* in Python.

Reproduction:

```
symbol = 'a'
Alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'     
num = Alphabet.find(symbol.upper())     
print num
```

http://ideone.com/cUD1uz

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use Dictionaries, If Loops, and Lists to contain the information. I will tell you how you can make this code.

First, we have to create a shifted dictionary function, you will find why later:

```
def shift_dict(Caesar, Shift):
  dic_len = len(Caesar)
  Shift = Shift % dic_len
  list_dic = [(k,v) for k, v in iter(Caesar.items())]
  Shifted = {
    list_dic[x][0]: list_dic[(x - Shift) % dic_len][1]
    for x in range(dic_len)
  }
  return Shifted
```

Okay, now we will create the dictionaries, the "Shift-ee's", These lists will help the code or so: The shift which will keep on changing:

```
Viginere = {
  "A":0,
  "B":1,
  "C":2,
  "D":3,
  "E":4,
  "F":5,
  "G":6,
  "H":7,
  "I":8,
  "J":9,
  "K":10,
  "L":11,
  "M":12,
  "N":13,
  "O":14,
  "P":15,
  "Q":16,
  "R":17,
  "S":18,
  "T":19,
  "U":20,
  "V":21,
  "W":22,
  "X":23,
  "Y":24,
  "Z":25
}
```

This is the shift, the code for the shift.
This is the VFU, the Viginere - For - Upper, which will return the capital-encrypted-text for Uppercase:

```
VFU = {
  0:"A",
  1:"B",
  2:"C",
  3:"D",
  4:"E",
  5:"F",
  6:"G",
  7:"H",
  8:"I",
  9:"J",
  10:"K",
  11:"L",
  12:"M",
  13:"N",
  14:"O",
  15:"P",
  16:"Q",
  17:"R",
  18:"S",
  19:"T",
  20:"U",
  21:"V",
  22:"W",
  23:"X",
  24:"Y",
  25:"Z"
}
```

Next, the VFL, the Viginere - For - Lower:

```
VFL = {
  0:"a",
  1:"b",
  2:"c",
  3:"d",
  4:"e",
  5:"f",
  6:"g",
  7:"h",
  8:"i",
  9:"j",
  10:"k",
  11:"l",
  12:"m",
  13:"n",
  14:"o",
  15:"p",
  16:"q",
  17:"r",
  18:"s",
  19:"t",
  20:"u",
  21:"v",
  22:"w",
  23:"x",
  24:"y",
  25:"z"
}
```

Now, we will create the main body:
The variables:

```
Asker = int(input("Do you want to... 1. Encode, or 2. Decode? "))
X = 0
Lister = []
Text = list(str(input("")))
Key = list(str(input("")).upper().replace(" ", "")
Z = 0
```

To encode:

```
if Asker == 1:
  for i in range(len(Text)):
    Shift = Viginere[Key[(Z % len(Key))]]
    if Text[X].isalpha():
      LetterNum = Viginere[Text[X].upper()]
      Helper = (LetterNum + Shift) % 26
      if Text[X].isupper():
        Lister.append(VFU[Helper])
      else:
        Lister.append(VFL[Helper])
    else:
      Lister.append(Text[X])
      Z -= 1
    X += 1
    Z += 1
  print(*Lister, sep = "")
```

Now let's break this code up to see how it works:
The for loop runs for the entire length of the text:

```
Shift = Viginere[Key[(Z % len(Key))]]
```

This gives the shift, You can break this down easily.
Now we shift the dictionary, then return it to normal, which is exemplified in this code:

```
    if Text[X].isalpha():
      LetterNum = Viginere[Text[X].upper()]
      Helper = (LetterNum + Shift) % 26
      if Text[X].isupper():
        Lister.append(VFU[Helper])
      else:
        Lister.append(VFL[Helper])
    else:
      Lister.append(Text[X])
      Z -= 1
    X += 1
    Z += 1
  print(*Lister, sep = "")
```

This is the code for decoding:

```
elif Asker == 2:
  for i in range(len(Text)):
    Shift = Viginere[Key[(Z % len(Key))]]
    if Text[X].isalpha():
      LetterNum = Viginere[Text[X].upper()]
      Helper = (LetterNum - Shift) % 26
      if Text[X].isupper():
        Lister.append(VFU[Helper])
      else:
        Lister.append(VFL[Helper])
    else:
      Lister.append(Text[X])
      Z -= 1
    X += 1
    Z += 1
  print(*Lister, sep = "")
```

Now, when we run the combined code:

```
def shift_dict(Caesar, Shift):
  dic_len = len(Caesar)
  Shift = Shift % dic_len
  list_dic = [(k,v) for k, v in iter(Caesar.items())]
  Shifted = {
    list_dic[x][0]: list_dic[(x - Shift) % dic_len][1]
    for x in range(dic_len)
  }
  return Shifted

Viginere = {
  "A":0,
  "B":1,
  "C":2,
  "D":3,
  "E":4,
  "F":5,
  "G":6,
  "H":7,
  "I":8,
  "J":9,
  "K":10,
  "L":11,
  "M":12,
  "N":13,
  "O":14,
  "P":15,
  "Q":16,
  "R":17,
  "S":18,
  "T":19,
  "U":20,
  "V":21,
  "W":22,
  "X":23,
  "Y":24,
  "Z":25
}
VFU = {
  0:"A",
  1:"B",
  2:"C",
  3:"D",
  4:"E",
  5:"F",
  6:"G",
  7:"H",
  8:"I",
  9:"J",
  10:"K",
  11:"L",
  12:"M",
  13:"N",
  14:"O",
  15:"P",
  16:"Q",
  17:"R",
  18:"S",
  19:"T",
  20:"U",
  21:"V",
  22:"W",
  23:"X",
  24:"Y",
  25:"Z"
}
VFL = {
  0:"a",
  1:"b",
  2:"c",
  3:"d",
  4:"e",
  5:"f",
  6:"g",
  7:"h",
  8:"i",
  9:"j",
  10:"k",
  11:"l",
  12:"m",
  13:"n",
  14:"o",
  15:"p",
  16:"q",
  17:"r",
  18:"s",
  19:"t",
  20:"u",
  21:"v",
  22:"w",
  23:"x",
  24:"y",
  25:"z"
}

Asker = int(input("Do you want to... 1. Encode, or 2. Decode? "))
X = 0
Lister = []
Text = list(str(input("")))
Key = list(str(input("")).upper().replace(" ", "")
Z = 0

if Asker == 1:
  for i in range(len(Text)):
    Shift = Viginere[Key[(Z % len(Key))]]
    if Text[X].isalpha():
      LetterNum = Viginere[Text[X].upper()]
      Helper = (LetterNum + Shift) % 26
      if Text[X].isupper():
        Lister.append(VFU[Helper])
      else:
        Lister.append(VFL[Helper])
    else:
      Lister.append(Text[X])
      Z -= 1
    X += 1
    Z += 1
  print(*Lister, sep = "")
elif Asker == 2:
  for i in range(len(Text)):
    Shift = Viginere[Key[(Z % len(Key))]]
    if Text[X].isalpha():
      LetterNum = Viginere[Text[X].upper()]
      Helper = (LetterNum - Shift) % 26
      if Text[X].isupper():
        Lister.append(VFU[Helper])
      else:
        Lister.append(VFL[Helper])
    else:
      Lister.append(Text[X])
      Z -= 1
    X += 1
    Z += 1
  print(*Lister, sep = "")
```

This becomes:

```
Do you want to... 1. Encode, or 2. Decode? 1
Please encode, as you always have worked!
Python is Awesome
Ejxhgr mfckhw, oe cds tskngk hwzw kavzcw!
```

And:

```
Do you want to... 1. Encode, or 2. Decode? 2
Ejxhgr mfckhw, oe cds tskngk hwzw kavzcw!
Python is awesome
Please encode, as you always have worked!
```

Thanks for this really good problem. I realize this is after 5 years when it was created, but I just joined StackOverflow, I am in Middle School, I just found this and solved this.

Please tell if this helps, Thanks for this amazing Question!